# Facebook Login Button - Cancel URL

Tags: authentication, facebook, facebook-oauth

Is it possible to provide a cancel URL when using the [Facebook Login Button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's automatical cancel button when FB asks user wheter to allow or not to use your application

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to specify cancel URL which directs the user to when they hit the cancel button on the permissions request dialog? It'll be useful for explaining why certain permissions are required. Much like some Games & Apps on Facebook do.

Comment: @Lou: Browse around documentation and you'll 100% find something. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/events.cancel/